# Check host availability by MAC address

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, osi

Is it possible to check if host with secific MAC address are 'alive' ?

I do NOT want to use 3-rd layer ISO/OSI and ICMP ping message

Comment: Why? Are you aware that the MAC address can be changed by the user, so recording them elsewhere is basically futile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an [`ARP Ping`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/arping.8.html). This only works when you are physically on the same network segment. Read more about this on [Wikipedia's ARP Ping article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping).

Note that there are two different implementations of `arping`, one which can ping MAC addresses to resolve them to IP addresses and one that doesn't. The implementation in the iproute2 package does not do what you want, but [Thomas Habets implementatation](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=arping) does. This is also explained in the [Wikipedia ARP Ping article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping)

Comment: Arping nedd to know IP address, as I mentioned in question I do not want to use 3rd layer of OSI

Comment: @mason thats just not true. Edited my post to include a [manpage with better explanations](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/arping.8.html).